# Upload image on background, with Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

i have a upload form in my web site, that allow the users to insert some items(usually trees), and they have the option to upload images **after** they added this items.
to upload image its take something like 15 second, but i want let the users the option to add another item in the time they are waiting for the image to upload.
so i want to use thread because: 
after the upload will finish, the page will refresh and the form will reset, so they have to wait untill its will finish to upload if they want to add another item.

i tried this code:

```
  protected void UploadFile(Object s, EventArgs e)
        {
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
    {
      //code for upload the image
    )};
    t.Start();
}
```

but its not working, and its even not uploading the file now.
some one know the reason?
thanks.

Comment: Use ajax to upload images asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunk of time necessary to upload a file is not in the handling of it -- you are probably just saving the file somewhere -- it's the transmission of the file over the network.

So I would advise not to try to do background processing here, just handle it in the normal way, it will be just as performant. The user will just have to wait until the image is sent over the network.

If a user needs to add another item while his image is uploading, you can always let your site open another page in a tab/window on the browser.

Comment: i did it with another window, and put it in iframe and its great.

Comment: iFrame, that's a nice touch :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your server side code is called only after the complete request is received.
So using a thread there won't help much.

If you want to keep your page interactive even while the upload happens you should look for an ajax based solution.

A very simple option is [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). You can hook it up to an HttpHandler and have your uploads happen in the background while the application remains interactive.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can take a look at what [HTML5 can do for you](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/) in terms of giving more feedback to the user that his file is been uploaded. Like Roy pointed out, transmission time is important and the users are going to have to wait anyway. But with HTML5 perhaps you can provide some nice progress bar to improve the user experience of your upload page.

Hope this helps.